# Excel equation needed; if any phone number matches check to make sure names match in other column

Tags: excel, function, duplicates, match, equation

I work at a Federal Prison.  I have a spreadsheet that shows every inmates call with thier name and number they called.  I want to write an equation that will find duplicate phone numbers and if the duplicates have <> (not equal) names I want it highlighted or printed on a new tab or something.

Right now I have about 3K rows of calls.  I do a conditional formating to highlight the duplicate numbers, I sort biggest to smallest and then I look down this long sheet confirming the inmate names match.  It takes way too long.

I want a tab that automaticly displays:

Johnson  (123)456-7890
Smith    (123)456-7890

This will show me that in a duplicate phone number the names did not match.

What do you all think?

Thanks,

Matt.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a [PivotTable](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/pivottbls/create.php) with telephone numbers then names for ROWS (and maybe count of either for Σ  VALUES). More than one name under any one number should stand out visually without the need for anything more elaborate.